# Как в метод передавать только строго определённые аргументы (enum or string). Язык C#

Tags: c#

Есть метод и в него нужно предать заранее определённые "буквенные" варианты аргументов, для того что бы InteliSence давал подсказки того, что вобще можно ввести в это поле. Далее обработать это с помощью конструкции swich case.

Как я это себе представляю, но не представлю как сделать что бы работало.

```
public enum position { Director, Manager, Administrator, Secretary, Developer };

public float Salary (int position, int standing)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case Director:
                Console.WriteLine("Case Director");
                break;
            case Manager:
                Console.WriteLine("Case Manager");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }
        return ...;
    }
```

position в аргументных скобках никак не связан с enum.

Класс должен выглядеть как то так.

```
class Employee
{
    private string name;
    private string lastName;
    public enum Position { Director, Manager, Administrator, Secretary, Developer };
    Position position = Position.Developer;


    public Employee(string name, string lastName)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public float Salary(Position position, int standing)
    {
        switch (this.position)
        {
            case Director:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                break;
            case Manager:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Изучайте: http://blog.vkuznetsov.ru/posts/2011/09/25/malenkie-chudesa-csharp-net-zabavy-s-metodami-enum

Comment: Что значит «"буквенные" варианты аргументов»? Приведите пример желательного синтаксиса, что должно быть возможно, а что нет.

Comment: Назовите enum нормально, чтобы не было конфликта с локальной переменной position. Нужен enum - передавайте enum. Приходит int - переведите его в enum. в swicth используте же case ИмяЕнум.Director

Comment: @Алекс, давным давно, еще во времена СИ придумали битовые флаги для этого. Можно использовать не битовые - а обычные флаги (где нумерация идет с 0 и по порядку). Почитайте статью, там есть примеры свитч кейс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы хотите добиться такого эффекта:

```
    public enum Position { Director, Manager, Administrator, Secretary, Developer };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Position position = Position.Developer;
        Salary(position);
    }

    public static void Salary(Position position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case Position.Developer:
                Console.WriteLine("Case Developer");
                break;
            case Position.Administrator:
                Console.WriteLine("Case Administrator");
                break;
            //и т.д.
        }
    }
```

---

Если нужно принимать именно строку, то можно сделать так:

```
    public enum Position { Director, Manager, Administrator, Secretary, Developer };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Salary("Developer");
    }

    public static void Salary(string str)
    {
        Position position;
        var isValid = Enum.TryParse(str, out position);
        if (isValid)
            switch (position)
            {
                case Position.Developer:
                    Console.WriteLine("Case Developer");
                    break;
                case Position.Administrator:
                    Console.WriteLine("Case Administrator");
                    break;
                    //и т.д.
            }
    }
```

---

Адаптация под ваш класс:

```
public enum Position { Director, Manager, Administrator, Secretary, Developer };
class Employee
{
    private string name;
    private string lastName;
    Position _position = Position.Developer;


    public Employee(string name, string lastName)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        Salary(_position, 5);
    }

    public float Salary(Position position, int standing)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case Position.Developer:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                break;
            case Position.Manager:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, прямо то что нужно! Единственное нужно это под отдельный класс адаптировать. Думаю я это сделаю. Спасибо )

Comment: @Алекс, Пожалуйста!

Comment: Думал что получится адаптировать этот код под класс, но что то  не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Алекс, опишите в задании как должен выглядеть класс.

Comment: Скриншот добавил того что у меня есть.

Comment: @Алекс, лучше выложите код а не скриншот, я его отредактирую.

Comment: Выложил код класса.

Comment: @Алекс, добавил, смотрите.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше терпение.

Comment: Строка Position position = Position.Developer; лишняя.